Can't locate Spreadsheet/WriteExcel/Big.pm in @INC
I have spent all day chasing this error message that I keep getting when I try and execute a perl script.  the full error message is:
Can't locate Spreadsheet/WriteExcel/Big.pm in @INC (you may need to install the Spreadsheet::WriteExcel::Big module) (@INC contains: /loc02/mpdb/share/perl.d /loc02/mpdb/scripts/ /usr/share/perl5/vendor_perl/Spreadsheet/WriteExcel/Big.pm  /usr/share/perl5/vendor_perl/Spreadsheet/WriteExcel/Big.pm /home/oracle/frmhome/perl/lib/site_perl/5.36.0/x86_64-linux-thread-multi /home/oracle/frmhome/perl/lib/site_perl/5.36.0 /home/oracle/frmhome/perl/lib/5.36.0/x86_64-linux-thread-multi /home/oracle/frmhome/perl/lib/5.36.0) at /loc02/mpdb/scripts/veh_summ_write.pl line 1104.

I currently have in the line of the script that I am running the full path to the PM in the script.
#!/home/oracle/frmhome/perl/bin/perl -w -I /usr/share/perl5/vendor_perl/Spreadsheet/WriteExcel/Big.pm

How do I get this to work?

At the request of ikegami,
Output of head -n 1 /home/oracle/frmhome/perl/bin/cpan:
#!/home/oracle/frmhome/perl/bin/perl

Output of set | grep ^PERL:
PERL5LIB=/usr/share/perl5:/usr/share/perl5/vendor_perl

Output of /home/oracle/frmhome/perl/bin/perl -V:'inst.*':
installarchlib='/home/oracle/frmhome/perl/lib/5.36.0/x86_64-linux-thread-multi';
installbin='/home/oracle/frmhome/perl/bin';
installhtml1dir='';
installhtml3dir='';
installman1dir='/home/oracle/frmhome/perl/man/man1';
installman3dir='/home/oracle/frmhome/perl/man/man3';
installprefix='/home/oracle/frmhome/perl';
installprefixexp='/home/oracle/frmhome/perl/bin/..';
installprivlib='/home/oracle/frmhome/perl/lib/5.36.0';
installscript='/home/oracle/frmhome/perl/bin/';
installsitearch='/home/oracle/frmhome/perl/lib/site_perl/5.36.0/x86_64-linux-thread-multi';
installsitebin='/home/oracle/frmhome/perl/bin';
installsitehtml1dir='';
installsitehtml3dir='';
installsitelib='/home/oracle/frmhome/perl/lib/site_perl/5.36.0';
installsiteman1dir='/home/oracle/frmhome/perl/man/man1';
installsiteman3dir='/home/oracle/frmhome/perl/man/man3';
installsitescript='/home/oracle/frmhome/perl/bin';
installstyle='lib';
installusrbinperl='undef';
installvendorarch='';
installvendorbin='';
installvendorhtml1dir='';
installvendorhtml3dir='';
installvendorlib='';
installvendorman1dir='';
installvendorman3dir='';
installvendorscript='';


uh what? The first line of cpan is blank??? That makes no sense. It should be #!/home/oracle/frmhome/perl/bin/perl, or at least something that starts with #!. Something's wrong with that file.

Actually it is not blank, I think the way I pasted it in it wasn't showing correctly.  I fixed how it is display now.

You say you have PERL5LIB=/usr/share/perl5:/usr/share/perl5/vendor_perl, but that was the case earlier. That has the same effect as -I /usr/share/perl5/vendor_perl and use lib '/usr/share/perl5/vendor_perl'; and shouldn't be used for the same reasons

Given the information you provided, it should have installed properly. One last thing to check is echo 'o conf' | /home/oracle/frmhome/perl/bin/cpan | grep -P 'make|mbuild'

You should be providing the path to the lib directory, not the module itself. This means it should be -I /usr/share/perl5/vendor_perl.
BUT
One build of Perl shouldn't be using the install directory of a different build of Perl. Don't manipulate @INC (e.g. by using -I) here. Instead, install the module for the Perl in /home/oracle/frmhome/perl by using the cpan installed by that Perl. Perhaps
/home/oracle/frmhome/perl/bin/cpan Spreadsheet::WriteExcel::Big


Note that Spreadsheet::WriteExcel::Big is deprecated.

The module was a sub-class of Spreadsheet::WriteExcel used for creating Excel files greater than 7MB. However, it is no longer required and is now deprecated.
As of version 2.17 Spreadsheet::WriteExcel can create files larger than 7MB directly if OLE::Storage_Lite is installed.
This module only exists for backwards compatibility. If your programs use ::Big you should convert them to use Spreadsheet::WritExcel directly.


I guess should explain more of what I had tried to do before I posted. initially I did try the line with -I /usr/share/perl5/vendor_perl.  When that did not work I tried adding folders.  Maybe if I try CPAN that will fix the issue.
I know that Spreadsheet::WriteExcel::Big has been deprecated. But I actually think that a lot of the functionality in this application has been deprecated over time The reason I am dealing with this at all is because trying to migrate it off of old servers ,

I just ran the command  /home/oracle/frmhome/perl/bin/cpan Spreadsheet::WriteExcel::Big on the server and received results that it was successful.  I Then removed all of the cases where modified the script to add includes that were not originally in it. However, when I tried the script again I am still getting the same error message.

Is Spreadsheet/WriteExcel/Big.pm found in a subdir of /home/oracle/frmhome/perl?

No, even after running cpan the only instance I see of Spreadsheet/WriteExcel/Big.pm is located in /usr/share/perl5/vendor_perl/

See the edit I made to your question. Please fill in the blanks.

I provided the information you were asking for.  Actually I was also trying something in the script that actually appears to have gotten me past the issue.  I will post what I did as an answer to my question.

Me being me while I was waiting for responses I tried some experiments to see if I could find a way around the problem.
I added this line of code to the script and it got me past the issue
use lib '/usr/share/perl5/vendor_perl';

Well done. We actually had similar questions recently with that answer.

This is wrong. You shouldn't be manipulating @INC to cause modules installed by a different build of Perl to be used, which means you shouldn't be using the installation of the module found in /usr/share/perl5/vendor_perl. "Solutions" that cause that installation to be used (such as previously-mentioned -I /usr/share/perl5/vendor_perl, as well as use lib '/usr/share/perl5/vendor_perl';) are going to cause you problems.

after I ran the command  /home/oracle/frmhome/perl/bin/cpan Spreadsheet::WriteExcel::Big  which was successful. I did a search for where Big.pm was installed. The only instance of Big.pm on the server is that one.  using the use lib '/usr/share/perl5/vendor_perl'; worked where  -I /usr/share/perl5/vendor_perl did not. you may think it is wrong but this how I have script working on RHEL8 the same way it did on RHEL7.
